# Creating c# web service - having questions in creating structure

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-serialization

I am creating c# webservice. Some other server will push the data frequently into the web method. Now i have to validate this xml and do some operations on that data and return the acknowledgement.

1. The request i will get from server in my WS, will be XML or i need to deserialize that?
2. There will will be username/password in soap request. What is the best way to authenticate re1uest?
3. How can i send back acknowledgement to the server? I need to post the SOAP response and serialize and send?

Please help me on this. I am new to creating web service.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to use a web service stack provided? will this be an asmx or WCF service hosted in IIS? Both will support SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is for sure, you always need to serialize / deserialize your data upon receive  / transmit. If you are also sending a username and password you should also encrypt the data using your own encryption algorythm. PS: JSON is my favourite way to go because its lightweight.